# Is it possible to password protect a printer on the LAN?

Tags: networking, printing, printer, lan, network-printer

Is it possible to password protect a printer on the LAN ?

Im about to move to a serviced office where they have an open LAN. Eg. no VLANs for individual companies. And i want to have my own printer, but dont want others on the LAN to be able to access it.

Of course i could just connect to the printer over USB only. But then i would not be able to use Google cloud print etc.

The printer is an Epson WF-7620

My computer is a Macbook Pro running OSX 10.14.x

Comment: Use another computer e.g. a Raspberry Pi with CUPS and Google print service that has a direct link to the printer. This is how we deal with an old non Google printer in a serviced office. We authorise Print permission based on GSuite accounts. So not password protected exactly.

Comment: Use a firewall. Any cheap NAT router will do.

Comment: The answer is to segregate the network as suggested by @DanielB. Password protecting your printer is not the question The question is how do you protect ALL of your equipment on an untrusted network. The answer is, you make a new network with a router.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, except if the printer supports it. What you could try, if your router supports it, is to make your router only allow traffic from the device you want to print from to the printer. This wouldn't use GCP, instead it would directly connect.

EDIT: You could buy a pretty cheap router from Amazon or something and connect it in your office. Password protect the wifi and connect your printer. Boom done!